Deleting special characters from QGIS Attribute table
Is there a way to delete special characters such as *?
I've tried using replace and regexp_replace, but my version at least doesn't recognise special characters.
There are hundreds of fields, and I'm wondering if it's possible to delete specific special characters.


Using Regular expressions, to keep only numbers and hypens, use:
regexp_replace (name,'[^\\d|-]','')

Explanation: ^ (hat): exlxude the following: \\d (any digit); |: logical or - hyphen; [] to match specific characters (those defined: a hyphen or not a digit). So this matches to everything that is not a hyphen or a digit and replaces it with an empty string (deltes it).

Variant, to show how the syntax works for simple replace() and Regular expressions, see here how to replace just the asterisk *:
replace (name,'*','')

or
regexp_replace (name,'\\*','')

Using regular expression, * is a quantifier and has to be masked with \\.

This regex_replace replaces all characters that are NOT characters from the alphabet (A-Z / a-z) or numbers (0-9) or "-" or a space (" "):
Note, that i use a different field name. So make sure, to replace "test", with your field name!
regexp_replace("test", '[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]', '')

Before:

After:

